# Unable to load library 'libtesseract302':Module cannot be found (Windows10)

Tags: java, exception, ocr, tesseract

We are trying to make software for a car parking system using image processing. We used OCR. We intend to use a webcam to obtain images of the license plate when the vehicle leaves and enters. We will then use the number to calculate the time spent inside the park and price tickets based on that.
This is my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import net.sourceforge.tess4j.ITesseract;
import net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract1;
import net.sourceforge.tess4j.TesseractException;
public class TestOCR {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

                File imageFile = new File("C:"+File.separator+"projects"+File.separator+"plate.tif");
                //ITesseract instance = new Tesseract();  // JNA Interface Mapping
                ITesseract instance = new Tesseract1(); // JNA Direct Mapping

                try {
                    //String result = instance.doOCR(imageFile);
                    //stem.out.println(result);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                }


    }

}
```

---

When I run this, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'libtesseract302': The specified module could not be found.

    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:145)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:188)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:123)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:255)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:241)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.TessAPI.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
    at com.nadeem.app.ocr.TesseractExample.main(TesseractExample.java:16)
```

Initially we had a NoSuchFieldError and after using Maven to fix that we encountered this problem.

Comment: Add the  complete Stacktrace.

Comment: I added the complete Stacktrace

Comment: Looks like you have not installed the native libs

Comment: Can you tell me how to?

Comment: And which libraries exactly?

Comment: Which operating system do you use?

Comment: Than put the dll's which you can find in the zip file into WINDOWS/System32 Directory and try again.

Comment: Okay. But can you please tell me which dll's exactly and where to find them? Thank you.

Comment: If you download the Distribution from the Webpage, there must be a file called libtesseract302.dll inside. and this dll you have to copy.

Comment: Did not work still...

Answer (score 0):

Basically this error would come either of below reasons

1. dll path are not specified properly. You can add in vm argument as below. `-Djna.library.path=<folder_contains_dll>`, This folder should have three dll files gsdll64.dll,liblept168.dll and libtesseract302.dll
2. You should have  Visual C++ Redistributable for VS2012 installed. Windows 10 doesn't have this installed by default.

You may do below steps to start with

1. Install Visual C++ Redistributable for VS2012 if its not installed
2. Clone the project from https://github.com/mnadeem/ocr-tess4j-example
3. Import the maven project in eclipse
4. Run the Java class TesseractExample.java

Comment: I think you didn't configured properly. I just tested with below steps  and working fine for me.

1. Installed  Visual C++ Redistributable for VS2012
2. Clone the project from https://github.com/mnadeem/ocr-tess4j-example
3. Imported the maven project in eclipse
4. Run the Java class TesseractExample.java
5. Getting results

Comment: Hey! Thanks for all the help. We got it working now!

Comment: Good, Did you get it worked by following above steps or any other issues?

Comment: We couldn't identify the missing library. So we used Maven to update automatically. Thank you for your time!